# detail not found when overriding get_queryset in ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm overriding get_queryset in a ModelViewSet to support "me" as filter and multiple pk search:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = UserProfile.objects.all() 
serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer    

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = UserProfile.objects.all() 

    if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
        pk_user = self.kwargs['pk']

        if ',' in pk_user: # Multiquery             
            pk_users = pk_user.split(',')
            qs = qs.filter(pk__in=pk_users)
        elif pk_user == "me":
            qs = qs.filter(pk=self.request.user)
        else:
            qs = qs.filter(pk=pk_user)

    # By default return all the items           
    return qs
```

I'm using the following serializer:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar_thumbnail_small = serializers.ImageField(read_only=True)
    avatar_thumbnail_medium = serializers.ImageField(read_only=True)

    id = serializers.CharField(source='user.id')
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    firstname = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name')
    lastname = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name')


    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'karma', 'avatar_thumbnail_small', 'avatar_thumbnail_medium', 'contacts', 'suggested_contacts')
```

and I've registered the url in urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', app.views_rest.UserViewSet, base_name="users")
```

but when I tried to GET the url /api/users/2,3/ or /api/users/me/ it gives a json message saying that detail is not found.

/api/users/2/, /api/users/3/ and /api/users/ works fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not very sure but I think the router only accepts a single number for the pk kwarg. The internal regex is probably something like `(?P<pk>\d+)`

Comment: As you can see I'm using a router that handles the parameters. In fact, If I print(self.kwargs['pk']) I sucessfully receive the "me" parameter.

Comment: Then you should show the rest of the code for that router.

Comment: Here it is: 

`router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', app.views_rest.UserViewSet, base_name="users")`

Comment: Where are you putting that print call?

Comment: Inside def get_queryset(self):

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because the retrieve action also calls the `get_object` after and you didn't overrode it. See https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L76